# Converting a Location to LatLng

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I'm trying to set the marker on my current location, so I tried to convert a Location to a LatLng class:

```
LatLng mCurrentPlace= new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
```

Then I recalled the addMarker method:

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title(getString(R.string.default_info_title))
    .position(mCurrentPlace)
    .snippet(getString(R.string.default_info_snippet)))
```

But Launching the application by "Run", it arrested.

Where am I goning wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: arrested? you mean it crashed? if so, whats the  traceback on the logcat?

Comment: arrested? what do you mean

Answer (score 4):

```
  public void moveMap(GoogleMap gMap, double latitude, double longitude) {
        Log.v(TAG, "mapMoved: " + gMap);
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 6);
        gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng));
        gMap.moveCamera(cu);
    }
```

Call this method where you want location and marker and in on mapasync callback method.

```
@Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            MapsInitializer.initialize(context);
            gMap = googleMap;
            gMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            if(items.get(getLayoutPosition())!=null )
                moveMap(gMap,latitude, longitude);
        }
        public void initializeMapView() {
            if (mapView != null) {
                // Initialise the MapView
                mapView.onCreate(null);
                // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
                mapView.getMapAsync(this);

            }
        }
```

Override onMapReadyCallback method and do this.

> Call initializeMapView method in `onCreate()` or In adapter `onBindViewHolder`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `LatLng.Builder`

```
LatLng.Builder builder = LatLng.newBuilder();
builder.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
builder.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
latLng = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

## MAP Activity

```
public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

LatLng loc;
Location location;
private double currentLatitude = 0;
private double currentLongitude = 0;
LocationManager locationManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or atLnmove the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
            * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
            */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker 
in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLg(sydney));

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(MapsActivity2.this);

}



public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    }
    // return latitude
    return currentLatitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    // return longitude
    return currentLongitude;
}

@Override
public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
    location=mMap.getMyLocation();
    currentLatitude=getLatitude();
    currentLongitude=getLongitude();

    LatLng currentLocation = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentLocation));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation).title("Marker in Current Location"));


    return false;
}
}
```

## Resource XML

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.atziant.parashar.gmapsapi.MapsActivity2" />
```